# Application minimized on its own after start

Tags: android

I have a project that I developed two years ago for android version 4.2. The project was successfully completed and the application worked. Now I want to resume it, but when it is launched on android 5.0, it collapses at the very beginning and it is not possible to expand it back. When the application is minimized, when viewing all running applications (left button on the phone), you can see that the application has an interface. When you try to expand the application, it expands again.

I don't understand at all why this is happening, and I don't know if it's related to a newer version of android. I don't post the application code because I don't know what part of it to post. There are no errors or error messages in android studio console.

If this is important, then the application uses bluetooth.

**I reduce my app code to be able to publish here.**

Console output:

```
11/11 19:40:22: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-J320FN.
Install successfully finished in 11 s 337 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 12497 on device 'samsung-sm_j320fn-420057d5ce3aa300'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote: v2
I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J320FN_5.1.1_0073
E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/art: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) failed for pid 12497: Operation not permitted
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10130
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.myapp rsrc of package com.example.myapp
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.myapp
I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.example.myapp, Feature store :{}
I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.myapp rsrc of package com.example.myapp
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.myapp rsrc of package com.example.myapp
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.myapp rsrc of package com.example.myapp
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.myapp rsrc of package com.example.myapp
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080946 (t=7 e=2374) (error -75)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/PERMISSIONS: check
D/PERMISSIONS: check 2
D/PERMISSIONS: onot GUI
D/PERMISSIONS: check 3
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.example.myapp.MainActivity isFragment :false
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
D/PERMISSIONS: check permission
D/PERMISSIONS: check permission
D/PERMISSIONS: check permission
D/PERMISSIONS: check permission
D/PERMISSIONS: check permission
D/PERMISSIONS: check permission
D/PERMISSIONS: check permission
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/PERMISSIONS: create options menue
I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.example.myapp.MainActivity
I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.example.myapp.MainActivity
D/InputMethodManager: windowDismissed mLockisused = false
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <!-- If you want to declare that your app is available to BLE-capable devices only, include the following in your app's manifest:/-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Some of Activity code:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_MICROPHONE = 0;
    DeviceListDialog deviceListDialogfragment = null;
    OpenFileDialog openDialogfragment = null;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int reqestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(reqestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(reqestCode == REQUEST_MICROPHONE){
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; ++i) {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "check permission");
                if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    this.finish();

    }}}
    private void aksPermission(String s){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, s) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{s}, REQUEST_MICROPHONE);
    }
    private boolean hasPermissions(String[] permissions) {
        if(permissions != null){
            for(String perm : permissions){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    return false;
        }}
        return true;
    }
    private void askPermissions(){
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT};
        if (!hasPermissions(permissions)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_MICROPHONE);
        }
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "check");
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "check 2");
    }
    
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        askPermissions();
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        initGUI();
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "check 3");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "check redtore instances");
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void initGUI(){
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "onot GUI");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "create options menue");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "item selected");
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MainActivity Layout layer XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Kamizelka.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Kamizelka.AppBarOverlay"
            app:title="Kamizelka Application" />



    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>




<!--    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
-->


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What does "collapse"/"minimise" mean?

Comment: it's similar to what happens to apps when you press the Home button. The application leaves the visible area of the screen, but remains in the device's RAM. Usually, after that, the application can be returned using the Overview button.

Comment: ok so you mean it closes. So, after you return to the application from the recents, does it close again or not?

Comment: Exactly. After trying to return via the Overview button, the application is immediately minimized again.

Comment: Which activity does it close on? Can you share the manifest, that activity's code and the buid.gradle?

Comment: The issue seems as this line keeps repeating: `D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
W/ResourceType: Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010034`

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity layout XML?

Comment: Originally it is too long, but I reduce it to be able to post here. I change console output and other stuff also. Will hope I don't cut something important.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, the problem turned out to be in terms of obtaining permissions. I will create a new topic with a question, I consider this closed.